# Как ввести промо коды в код андроид приложения?

Tags: android, testng, google-play-console, android-billing, promotions

Как с помощью `Google Play Console` или каких-то других ресурсов обеспечить полную подписку на приложения для своих друзей?
Для себя я когда тестировал покупки сделал полную версию но теперь тем же способом хочу сделать для друзей и у меня не получается.
Я добавил их электронные почты которые закреплены на их смартфонах в `Google Play Console` в раздел тестировщики, записал их по ссылке на тестирование и даже выпустил версию приложение на альфа и бета тест, но к сожаление это ничего не дает. ***Тестовая кредитная карта*** в них почему-то не отображается помогите выяснить в чем причина?
Промокоды как ввести в андроид приложение

Comment: используйте промокоды на контент. Посмотрите здесь: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime

Comment: а там ещё пишется что нужно как то это реализовать в коде приложение. Можете описать как это действует? или просто хватит идентификатора покупки?

Comment: С промокодами для инаппа не разбирался. Да, там что-то добавлять в код надо, просто так не сработает